# Select time from database after choose a ticket number

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to make a edit / update function based from searching ticket number. When user type a ticket number he had, would appear a form that contains data from database based on ticket number that he had.I can see name value, ticket number value and date value from database but I can't see a clock time value in select tag.

```
<?php
$no = $_GET['ticket'];
$st = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE no='$no'";
$check = mysql_query($st,$connection) or die("Failed");
$c = mysql_fetch_array($check);
?>
<form name="form" method="POST" action="">
   <table>
      <tr>
          <td>Reference Number</td>
          <td> : </td>
          <td>
              <input type="text" name="no" value="<?php echo $c['no'] ;?>" disabled>
              <input type="hidden" name="no" value="<?php echo $c['no'] ;?>">
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td> : </td>
          <td>
              <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $c['name'] ;?>" disabled>
              <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $c['name'] ;?>" disabled>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Date</td>
          <td> : </td>
          <td>
              <input type="text" id="date" name="date" value="<?php echo $c['date'] ;?>">
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Clock Time</td>
          <td> : </td>
          <td>
              <select name="time" value="<?php echo $c['time'] ;?>">
          </td>
      </tr>
```

I want to see the clock time value on database in select tag. After that, if user want to make changes on clock time based on the date he chosen, he can do that thing.

Thanks before,

Comment: Why would you use <SELECT> for the time and not <INPUT> like the date?

Comment: Because I need after select a date, a time will be filtering to show the time that were not in that date. Example in database I have 2 data 22-07-2013 13.00 and 28-07-2013 14.00. If user want to change date from 22-07-2013 to 28-07-2013 then he choose time, he can't find 14.00 time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stucture of drop down in htm is

```
<select name ="postname">
<option value="postvalue"> display value</option>
more options
.
.
.
.
</select>
```

use following code in your case

```
<select name="postname" >
   <option value="<?php echo $c['date'] ;?>" > <?php echo $c['date'] ;?> </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I need to see the clock time from database into select tag..

Answer (score 0):

select tags must have options. you need to popuate the select tag with options and then check it against your value to set the selected option.

this method is wrong `<select name="time" value="<?php echo $c['date'] ;?>">`

```
   <select name="time">
       <?php foreach($options as $option) { ?>
             <?php $sel = ''; if ($option->value = $c['date']) { $sel = 'selected'; } ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $option->value; ?>" <?php echo $sel; ?>><?php echo $option->name; ?></option>
       <?php } ?>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

put your select like this:-

```
 <select name="time" >
   <option value=value="<?php echo $c['date'] ;?>" selected > <?php echo $c['date'] ;?> </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I need to see the clock time from database into select tag.. I've tried with this but I can't see a clock time value